# App crashes when I hit "Run", but when I hit "Stop" then "Run"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4

In the simulator, my app crashes when I hit "Run" button. But if I hit "Stop" first and then "Run" the app from the simulator it works like a charm.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Huh?  What does 'crash' mean?  is there anything printed in the log?

Comment: When I hit a certain button in the app, the simulator crashes and xcode gives me a breakpoint! The breakpoint is where I call a function. But if I hit "Stop" after the simulator has crashed, I can start the app and it works just fine! So I don't think there is anything wrong with the code? Otherwise it wouldn't have worked anyway!

Comment: where can i find that log? :o (yes, im a noob ;) )

Comment: 1. Disable the breakpoint and run again. 2. in the upper-right part of Xcode, click the centermost button of the 'View' control.

Comment: I disabled it, but it still crashes!

Comment: self Fra_ga *const 0x00009f6c

That is shown in the log!

Comment: What line does it crash on, and is there a breakpoint on it?

Comment: it says thread1:breakpoint2.1!

Comment: Oh, now it is working! I had more breakpoints enabled apparently :P But anyway, now I know what breakpoints is! Thank you, CodaFi!

Comment: Don't let it get you down, we all had to start somewhere, eh?  Remember to mark as accepted, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable **every** single breakpoint in your app and run again.  Your app isn't 'crashing', the debugger is stopping it so you can step through your code. Then when you quit it, it is no longer in debug mode, so the breakpoints are ignored and your app executes as though they had never been placed.